# WordPress - Adding dynamic video content into Divi page template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode, dynamic-content, divi

I've added a code snippet (Snippets plug-in) in WordPress that creates a shortcode that we can use to display dynamic video on a page template. The video field comes from a custom field (file field) that we've added using ACF. This code works to display the video, **however we are trying to get it to display the thumbnail image for the video**, which is also using a dynamic field, and that is not working. We have followed this article: https://speckyboy.com/html5-video-wordpress-custom-fields/, but instead created a custom short code rather than running the code on the back-end (because we are using Divi, we want to be able to insert the short code from the front-end). Here is the snippet:

```
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function wpb_video_shortcode() { 
  
// Get the Video Fields
$video_mp4 =  get_field('video_mp4'); 
$video_thumbnail  = get_field('video_thumbnail'); 

// Build the  Shortcode
$attr =  array(
'mp4'      => $video_mp4,
'poster'   => $video_thumbnail,
'preload'  => 'auto'
);

// Output needs to be return
return $attr;
 }
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('course_video', 'wpb_video_shortcode');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcode functions should *echo* HTML. Yours *returns* an array of attributes.

Try this for the last line of your function.

```
echo wp_video_shortcode( $attr );
```

The tutorial you followed is clear about this.

Comment: hmm unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: View Source ... in your browser may help you figure out what's wrong.